# How can I minimise a rota or roster from a set of days I know somebody can work?

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming

I have a number of workers, in this case 5, who I want to spread over as many days as possible based on the days they are able to work. So, for example, I have this set up:

```
workers <- data.frame(worker = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                      monday = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                      tuesday = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                      wednesday = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                      thursday = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                      friday = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0))
```

The output of this optimisation I'm looking for is something like the following data frame:

```
workers <- data.frame(worker = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                      monday = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                      tuesday = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                      wednesday = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                      thursday = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                      friday = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

I should mention that there will sometimes be occasions where it's not possible to do put someone on all 5 days and that doesn't matter, I just like the best possible fit. If that means 2 people working on Monday, 1 person on Tuesday, Wednesday and Friday, but nobody on Thursday then that's fine.

I've taken a look at lpSolve, but I couldn't get it to define the answer for me. With a little manipulation of `workers` above, it will only shows an output of:

```
> workers_edit
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    1
> lp.assign(workers_edit)
Success: the objective function is 0 
> lp.assign(workers_edit)$solution
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1
[5,]    1    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: can you check `lpSolve`

Comment: you may need to specify the constraints

Comment: What exactly is "the best possible fit"? In my view, the best fit is just to use your original availability data frame as a solution. The best would be to specify your problem in a mathematical model.

Comment: Sorry @ErwinKalvelagen, I'm looking for each person to work "no more than one day". So each row (worker) should have only one "1", with each column used if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely clear what the model is, so first fill-in the gaps.

1. Each worker can only work exactly 1 day
2. "best fit" is here defined as: the number of workers working at a given day is most evenly distributed.

Now let's make this more precise with developing a mathematical model:

We define a binary variable:

```
work(w,t) = 1 if worker w works during day t
            0 otherwise
```

Also, introduce a variable

```
 wnum(t) = number of workers active at day t
```

The most evenly distributed schedule is designed by minimizing the difference between the maximum number of workers `wnum(t)` and the minimum. So, we end up with:

[image]

This is a simple Mixed Integer Programming model that can be solved with any MIP solver. I implemented it here using CVXR:

```
> library(CVXR)
> 
> workers <- data.frame(worker = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
+                       monday = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
+                       tuesday = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
+                       wednesday = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
+                       thursday = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
+                       friday = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0))
> workers
  worker monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday
1      A      1       0         0        1      0
2      B      1       0         0        0      1
3      C      1       1         1        1      0
4      D      0       0         1        0      1
5      E      0       1         0        0      0
> 
> # convert to matrix
> available <- as.matrix(workers[,-1])
> available
     monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday
[1,]      1       0         0        1      0
[2,]      1       0         0        0      1
[3,]      1       1         1        1      0
[4,]      0       0         1        0      1
[5,]      0       1         0        0      0
> 
> # sizes
> m <- nrow(available)
> n <- ncol(available)
> 
> # decision variables
> work <- Variable(m,n,boolean=T)
> wnum <- Variable(n)
> wmax <- Variable(1)
> wmin <- Variable(1)
> 
> # optimization model
> problem <- Problem(Minimize(wmax-wmin),
+                    list(sum_entries(work,axis=1)==1,
+                         wnum==sum_entries(work,axis=2),
+                         work <= available,
+                         wmax >= wnum,
+                         wmin <= wnum))
> 
> result <- solve(problem,verbose=T)
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.47
45 rows, 32 columns, 100 non-zeros
      0: obj =  0.000000000e+000  infeas = 5.000e+000 (10)
*    19: obj =  2.000000000e+000  infeas = 0.000e+000 (2)
*    33: obj =  0.000000000e+000  infeas = 0.000e+000 (0)
OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
GLPK Integer Optimizer, v4.47
45 rows, 32 columns, 100 non-zeros
25 integer variables, all of which are binary
Integer optimization begins...
+    33: mip =     not found yet >=              -inf        (1; 0)
+    34: >>>>>  0.000000000e+000 >=  0.000000000e+000   0.0% (1; 0)
+    34: mip =  0.000000000e+000 >=     tree is empty   0.0% (0; 1)
INTEGER OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
> cat("status:",result$status)
status: optimal
> cat("objective:",result$value)
objective: 0
> print(result$getValue(work))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    1    0    0    0
>
```

Comment: Boolean is important. Without it, you would declare a continuous variable. "Incompatible dimensions" sounds like there is a mistake. My code worked without errors. You may need to install the package Rglpk for the glpk solver.

Comment: Thanks for this code, you've summed up the problem perfectly. It looks like it should do the trick, but I'm having an issue where it looks like the `Boolean` argument in the `Variable` function doesn't exist in the documentation and without it the `Problem` function throws an error about incompatible dimensions. Any ideas?